# Что сделать, чтобы всплывающие окна всегда срабатывали?

Tags: fancybox

Посмотрите пожалуйста http://html5.eu.org/ , там есть картинки, которые открываются в всплывающем окне, но если прокрутить карусель несколько раз (сделать круг), то картинки уже не открываются в сплывающем окне. Что сделать, чтобы всплывающее окно всегда работало?

Comment: Я честно не смог прочитать boutique.js даже с бьютифаером, скорее всего он ведет себя как мразь и вместо перестановки элементов создает их заново (при этом теряются все обработчики). Другими словами, __если я прав__, то при использовании этой карусели можно только заново вешать обработчики фэнсибокса.

Comment: "заново вешать обработчики фэнсибокса" - как это делается?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

смотрите строки 42-117

1. `$("#various2").fancybox()`
       зачем-то вызывается 3 раза, при том
       что такого элемента на странице
       вообще нет
2. `$(".example1 a").fancybox()` аналогично, хотя
       судя по вашей разметке нужно 2
       лишних вызова удалить и .example1
       исправить на .example2 по самому
       плагину ничего сказать не могу,
       видимо документацию показывают
       только после его покупки)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
1. Такой элемент есть на странице, два раза убрал, если убрать совсем, то перестанет работать всплывающее окно по ссылке «Написать» внизу картинок.
2. Удалил лишнее и исправил, спасибо. Сам jquery.boutique.min.js я изменил, сейчас вернул оригинал. 
Проблема остаётся.